# Will Windows work If I were to remove all the fonts preinstalled on it except one or completely nothing?

Tags: fonts

Take the situation. I only want one or zero fonts, no more.
How can I know if my Windows is working correctly?

Comment: Don't do that. It will break Windows.

Comment: Here's a better question - *why*?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not as that will likely break Windows. The three buttons (minimize, Window, Close) are fonts. There are other fonts used by Windows apps, and other apps you may (or I may) install.

Having all the fonts is not an issue and has never been going all the way back to Windows 95.

So do not delete fonts just because you do not use them. That would not be a good idea.

Note:  Windows 10 Pro elaborately set up has a font folder < 400 MB (tiny) with 225 fonts.

Comment: Many of them will also be used as 'invisible' substitutions for odd glyphs you may meet in documents or on the web, making it an even worse idea.